# Remap 'diffget' and disable the binding to 'do'

Tags: key-bindings, vimdiff

Since the keys `o` and `p` are close and sometimes I mistype them.

I would like to remap `diffget` and disable `do`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disabled `do` You can remap it to `<nop>`.

```
nnoremap do <nop>
```

To remap `diffget` you could either

- Introduction a new command (e.g. `Dg`) that will have to start with an upper case.

```
command! Dg :diffget
```

- Or introduce an abbreviation

```
cnoreabbrev dg diffget
```

Or it's more sophisticated version that triggers the abbreviation only at the start of the line:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> dg (getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == "dg") ? 'diffget' : 'dg'
```

Comment: or `:nnoremap <keys> :…diffget…<CR>`/`:nnoremap <keys> do` (counts handled automatically)